# How to build JNI .dll?

Tags: java, windows, dll, java-native-interface

I have a java project in Eclipse that contains some JNI code. 
JNI code is cross platform - for Windows and Linux. How can I build a dll?

Thanks.

Comment: Give us some more details about the source you want to compile: C/C++? do you have a Makefile? Do you need other libraries to link to? ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to build a .DLL for Windows and .so for Linux. You would compile C code in Linux using this syntax:

```
gcc -shared yourcode.c -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.3/include/ -o yourLib.so
```

import in java using

```
static {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
        System.loadLibrary("yourlib");
    }
```

For Windows [How to compile C to DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509757/compile-c-source-to-a-dll)

Comment: Yes! I know how to build .so file for Linux. But don't know how to build a .dll for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have some `C/C++` code. To create a `dll` (windows) you have to compile your code  (you could use Visual C++ Express for example, or mingw: gcc). In linux just use `gcc` to build the library.

Once you built the library for you platform add it to the library path with `-Djava.library.path=<folder containing the library>`.

*hth*