Cannot load a native JNI library
I'm working on a Minecraft library for my own mods to use and i ran into a problem with JNI.
I'm still new to the JNI and c++ stuff so i might've made a mistake but after hours of searching i didn't find an answer to my problem.
Whenever i try to load the library whether from an absolute path or copying from it from within the jar into a temporary directory and loading it from there it always outputs this:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: E:\IdeaProjects\hmmm library\nativeLibSrc\hmmm.dll: The specified procedure could not be found
    at jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:388) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:232) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:174) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2394) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:755) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1953) ~[?:?]
    at dev.progames723.hmmm.utils.NativeUtil.init(NativeUtil.java:107) ~[hmmm-1.0-dev.jar:?]
    at dev.progames723.hmmm.HmmmLibrary.init(HmmmLibrary.java:63) ~[hmmm-1.0-dev.jar:?]
    at dev.progames723.hmmm.fabric.HmmmLibraryFabric.onInitialize(HmmmLibraryFabric.java:9) ~[main/:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.FabricLoaderImpl.invokeEntrypoints(FabricLoaderImpl.java:384) ~[fabric-loader-0.15.3.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.game.minecraft.Hooks.startClient(Hooks.java:52) ~[fabric-loader-0.15.3.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.<init>(Minecraft.java:466) ~[minecraft-merged-ec231b8e98-1.20.2-loom.mappings.1_20_2.layered+hash.668605046-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:214) ~[minecraft-merged-ec231b8e98-1.20.2-loom.mappings.1_20_2.layered+hash.668605046-v2.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.game.minecraft.MinecraftGameProvider.launch(MinecraftGameProvider.java:470) ~[fabric-loader-0.15.3.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.Knot.launch(Knot.java:74) ~[fabric-loader-0.15.3.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClient.main(KnotClient.java:23) ~[fabric-loader-0.15.3.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.devlaunchinjector.Main.main(Main.java:86) ~[dev-launch-injector-0.2.1+build.8.jar:?]
    at dev.architectury.transformer.TransformerRuntime.main(TransformerRuntime.java:220) ~[architectury-transformer-5.2.87-runtime.jar:?]

The source code for the library: https://github.com/Progames723/Hmmm/tree/master/nativeLibSrc/src/main
I've tried changing compiler arguments to the ones that i found but they never did anything meaningful.

It seems not a problem of finding the library on the given path, in that case the error would be different. Which compiler arguments are you using for building the shared library? May I suggest to see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509757/compile-c-source-to-a-dll

@FrancescoPoli my compiler arguments can be found inside my windows Makefile, they were too long for a comment

First thing I try when getting issues with JNI is to check that the DLL has all it's depends available.
Take a look at https://download.cnet.com/dependency-walker-64-bit/3000-2086_4-75785868.html or https://www.dependencywalker.com/ and check that the DLLs good.

Dependency walker seems to freeze every time i try to use it

@Progames723 It takes a long time to load a library in dependency walker. You could try https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies instead, which has lazily loading, so it's faster. Alternatively, you could use dumpbin which is a tool that comes with MSVC, together with its /DEPENDENTS flag to list dependencies of the library. In this case though, it looks like the dependencies can be found, but a particular function can not. That may indicate that a dependency has the wrong version (missing a function), or perhaps a different library with the same name is being loaded inadvertently.

@JornVernee I downloaded Dependencies and it's telling me that I'm missing some imports on libstdc++
